# Swap Fn and Control key on a MacBook Pro

Tags: keyboard

I use a MacBook at work and the <kbd>Fn</kbd> is exactly where I expect the <kbd>Control</kbd> key to be. Is there any way I can swap the two keys?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[KeyRemap4MacBook](http://pqrs.org/macosx/keyremap4macbook/) allows you to do this.

Comment: now Karabiner elements but yes this is correct.